# Is there a keyboard shortcut for safely closing a responsive application Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I've recently switched from OS X to Ubuntu and although I'm enjoying the new experience, I'm still trying to find equivalents for some of my favourite OS X features. 
Do any of you know if there's a 'CMD q' equivalent for Ubuntu or an appropriate command I could add to the keyboard shortcuts menu in settings?
I just want a quick shortcut that will safely close the current running application. I've seen plenty of 'kill unresponsive programs' posts, but nothing like this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use good old Ctrl+Q (for you "Apple+Q"), that works with most applications?

Comment: At which point one might need to distinguish between a program and a window of that program.

Comment: There's always an option to send SIGHUP to the process, but if I understand correctly, some programs can trap and ignore the signal and continue running

Comment: Guys, OP mentions command+q, which is simply equivalent to Ctrl + Q. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

There are actually two <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> alternatives for Ubuntu. One is very similar to <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>. This doesn't work on all programs, however, so you'll probably be better off using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: I'm not allowed to upvote your comment because I don't have enough reputation, so thank you for your help. :)